# DNS works with host, but not with wget

Tags: networking, dns, 16.10, lxc, docker

#### TL;DR

I've got a strange situation where I can do DNS lookups on some hosts but not others.  This seems to be related to resolv.conf having one nameserver entry pointing to my nameserver and another that is presumably to do with docker, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

#### The problem

I've been reading [Stéphane Graber's excellent introduction to LXD](https://www.stgraber.org/2016/03/11/lxd-2-0-introduction-to-lxd-112/) and wanted to try it out.  Therefore, I did:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G lxd <myusername>
$ newgrp lxd
$ sudo lxd init
```

I configured it with all of the default settings.  I then typed:

```
$ lxc image list images:
error: Get https://images.linuxcontainers.org/streams/v1/index.json: lookup images.linuxcontainers.org: no such host
```

#### Some tests

I tried accessing that address from a web browser on another PC and it worked fine.  So I figured something must be wrong with the DNS set-up, but:

```
$ host images.linuxcontainers.org
images.linuxcontainers.org is an alias for canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org.
canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org has address 91.189.91.21
canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org has address 91.189.88.37
canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1560:8001::21
canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1562::41
```

So I tried wget:

```
$ wget https://images.linuxcontainers.org/streams/v1/index.json
--2016-11-10 15:56:22--  https://images.linuxcontainers.org/streams/v1/index.json
Resolving images.linuxcontainers.org (images.linuxcontainers.org)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address "images.linuxcontainers.org"
```

which made me think that there was a problem with my internet connection, but if I use us.images.linuxcontainers.org (which I saw mention of somewhere on the web):

```
$ wget https://us.images.linuxcontainers.org/streams/v1/index.json
--2016-11-10 15:57:26--  https://us.images.linuxcontainers.org/streams/v1/index.json
Resolving us.images.linuxcontainers.org (us.images.linuxcontainers.org)... 91.189.91.21, 2001:67c:1562::41
Connecting to us.images.linuxcontainers.org (us.images.linuxcontainers.org)|91.189.91.21|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3086 (3.0K) [application/json]
Saving to: "index.json"

index.json                                100%[==================================================================================>]   3.01K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2016-11-10 15:57:26 (8.36 MB/s) - "index.json" saved [3086/3086]
```

I also tried canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org, which (according to `host` above) is what images.linuxcontainers.org is an alias of and that worked too, so it looks like `host` can lookup images.linuxcontainers.org, while `wget` and `lxc` cannot, **but** `wget` **can** access canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org and most other sites I've tried.

```
$ wget https://canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org/streams/v1/index.json
--2016-11-10 16:02:28--  https://canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org/streams/v1/index.json
Resolving canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org (canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org)... 91.189.91.21, 91.189.88.37
Connecting to canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org (canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org)|91.189.91.21|:443... connected.
ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches
        requested host name "canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org".
To connect to canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.

$ wget --no-check-certificate https://canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org/streams/v1/index.json
--2016-11-10 16:02:37--  https://canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org/streams/v1/index.json
Resolving canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org (canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org)... 91.189.88.37, 91.189.91.21
Connecting to canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org (canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org)|91.189.88.37|:443... connected.
WARNING: no certificate subject alternative name matches
        requested host name "canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org".
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://uk.images.linuxcontainers.org/streams/v1/index.json [following]
--2016-11-10 16:02:37--  https://uk.images.linuxcontainers.org/streams/v1/index.json
Resolving uk.images.linuxcontainers.org (uk.images.linuxcontainers.org)... 91.189.88.37, 2001:67c:1560:8001::21
Connecting to uk.images.linuxcontainers.org (uk.images.linuxcontainers.org)|91.189.88.37|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3086 (3.0K) [application/json]
Saving to: "index.json.1"

index.json.1                              100%[==================================================================================>]   3.01K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2016-11-10 16:02:38 (96.5 MB/s) - "index.json.1" saved [3086/3086]
```

I've also tried `wget -4` and `wget -6` to rule out IPv6 issues, but results were the same either way.  Finally I tried some other programs like `w3m` but no difference there either.

I'm obviously missing something; can anyone offer any advice on why I can't get `lxc` to download the image list?

#### The PC

The PC is a relatively new install running Ubuntu Server 16.10 with [very few additional packages](http://pastebin.com/jm2LHmCw) installed in the main host.  Docker is installed and running but no containers are up.  Interestingly, I recently rebooted into kernel 4.8.6 to test another problem I was having and with that kernel I could access images.linuxcontainers.org, but docker wouldn't start, so I'm wondering if this might be to do with docker.

#### Configuration

`/etc/resolv.conf` looks like this (but for some reason I'm not aware of, is actually a symlink to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`):

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.1.254
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search lan
```

If I do query the first listed nameserver I get the same result as if I don't append the nameserver address:

```
$ host images.linuxcontainers.org 192.168.1.254
images.linuxcontainers.org is an alias for canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org.
canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org has address 91.189.91.21
canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org has address 91.189.88.37
canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1560:8001::21
canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1562::41
```

If I do query the second, it times out without reaching a server:

```
$ host images.linuxcontainers.org 127.0.0.53
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

If I query the second but use the canonical name it works and then times out???

```
$ host canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org 127.0.0.53
Using domain server:
Name: 127.0.0.53
Address: 127.0.0.53#53
Aliases:

canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org has address 91.189.88.37
canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org has address 91.189.91.21
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

#### Edit 1:

`/etc/nsswitch.conf` looks like this:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

**Edit 2**

The modified nsswitch.conf now looks like this:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files resolve dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

**Edit 3**

Contents of /etc/systemd/resolved.conf:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
#Domains=
#LLMNR=yes
#DNSSEC=no
#Cache=yes
```

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` is usually a symlink on Ubuntu, that's normal. What does `/etc/nsswitch.conf` contain?

Comment: @muru I've added it above (this one isn't a symlink)

Comment: I know this may be a silly question, and is only a workaround, but have you thought about taking the domain name, and substituting the IP address?  Like this `http://91.189.91.21/streams/v1/index.json`.  Low tech, I know, but it provides a temporary workaround.

Comment: @ThatGuy Thanks for that.  This won't work with every server (as it depends on whether the server looks out for the domain name) - in this case I could just use canonical.images.linuxcontainers.org anyway as this seems to work.  However, I also would need to persuade `lxc image list` and `lxc launch` to use this instead of the built-in address.

Comment: Understood.  I run a custom DNS server if you'd like to use it for a workaround as well.  Just shoot me a message if you need.

Comment: Thanks @ThatGuy - I may yet resort to that, but first I'd like to understand why it doesn't work out of the box (given that - as far as I know - I haven't changed anything from the standard Ubuntu install).  There's obviously something I'm missing.

Comment: looks like docker is messing with your dns via the resolvconf system, i would disable docker completely if you are not using it

Comment: @Amias, thanks, but I'm using docker a lot; I just disabled the containers to ensure that they weren't having an impact.

Comment: @DrAl, This is the first time to see `resolve` hosts keyword, it seems wrong. You should have something like `hosts:          files dns [!UNAVAIL=return]` or if you have mDNS installed `files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4` . you can remove `[NOTFOUND=return]` or  `[!UNAVAIL=return]` , it's the default action anyway if nothing left to query.

Comment: @user.dz, I've tried removing this (although it is the default set up by my installation as I've never previously touched this file).  This seems to allow wget to work (albeit after a few seconds delay "resolving images.linuxcontainers.org).  Thank you!  Any idea why this might have been added to my /etc/nsswitch.conf?  The list of packages I've installed onto the server is listed in a link in the "The PC" section above.

Comment: @DrAl, For the delay issue,  could you post the new `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Comment: @user.dz - posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This is the first time to see `resolve` hosts keyword, it seems wrong. You should have something like

  ```
  hosts: files dns [NOTFOUND=return]
  ```

  or if you have mDNS installed

  ```
  hosts: files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4
  ```

  You can remove `[NOTFOUND=return]` or `[!UNAVAIL=return]` , it's the default action anyway if nothing left to query.
- Well, after some digging I could find that there is an NSS module new to me

  **`libnss-resolve`**

  > ```
  > nss module to resolve names via systemd-resolved
  >
  > nss-resolve is a plugin for the GNU Name Service Switch (NSS) functionality
  > of the GNU C Library (glibc) providing DNS and LLMNR resolution to programs via
  > the systemd-resolved daemon (provided in the systemd package).
  >
  > Installing this package automatically adds resolve to /etc/nsswitch.conf.
  > ```

  You could end up installing it somehow and not with the packages you mentioned. There is no package depends on it.

  ```
  ~$ apt-cache rdepends libnss-resolve
  libnss-resolve
  Reverse Depends:
  ```

  But I can't say anything right now, why `systemd-resolved` was unreliable. It is better to report it as bug in `systemd`.

Comment: Interesting, thank you.  I tried removing "resolve" and the `wget` got a lot quicker, so it looks like that was what was causing the problem.  My hosts line in the nsswitch.conf now just has "files dns".

Comment: I used `dpkg-query -l '*resolve*'` to check and found that `libnss-resolve` is installed, so I installed `aptitude` and ran `aptitude why libnss-resolve` and it says `i   ubuntu-standard Recommends libnss-resolve`.

Comment: @DrAl, which release is this?  I've U16.04  no such dependency between   `ubuntu-standard` & `libnss-resolve` .

Comment: it's 16.10.  I've just been searching the web and [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1624071) seems relevant.  It looks like this problem was introduced by a bug-fix if I'm understanding that page correctly.

Comment: That gives us some light about the current setup, but you have the last fix , which means this another bug (systemd-resolved/nss-resolve is unreliable). Do you have its service running `systemctl status systemd-resolved.service`

Comment: Seems to be: it says "active (running)". At the bottom are some log lines alternating between `Grace period over, resuming full feature set (UDP+EDNS0+DO+LARGE) for DNS server 192.168.1.254` and `Using degraded feature set (UDP+EDNS0+DO) for DNS server 192.168.1.254`

Comment: Looks to be entirely commented out, but I've posted it above under **Edit 3**

Comment: @DrAl, so it does use defaults, from `man resolved.conf` , that means we are back to `/etc/resolv.conf` :/ . `resolve` should have same effect as `dns` in `nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: That leaves me at a bit of a loss for what to raise as a bug report.  However, on a positive note, it's now working nicely, so I'm happy!  Thanks again.

Comment: @DrAl, That was the default setup, and did not work as it should, to me better to report that against `systemd`. If you think my answer works for you, please flag it accepted so others avoid going through all these comments. If I miss something, let me know :) too.

Comment: Had a similar problem with Arch Linux on LXC on Android (Pixel C, Android N). I was able to ping whatever I wanted, nslookup anything, but wasn't able to `pacman -Syu`, `curl http://google.com/` nor `wget google.com`, but `telnet google.com 80` worked fine. I fixed by putting `hosts: files dns [NOTFOUND=return]` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. Spent hours on this, thank you very much!!

Comment: @DenysVitali, nice to hear that. Your results add something to this case, it seems related to LXC/systemd combination. Please, if you have reported or gonna report this bug to systemd/ArchLinux or LXC. Let me know the link of bug report, some users (like me) may would like to know its root cause. I will add it to the answer.

Comment: If you want more infos you can find it [here](https://denv.it/blog/2017/03/14/arch-linux-on-pixel-c-via-lxc/), basically the wrong values were already embedded in Arch Linux for ARM (ALARM), I'll try to reach them out to discover what may cause this issue. Please note that Arch Linux (x86/amd64 edition) has `hosts: files mymachines resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname` by default, therefore the bug may be caused by systemd in some way when interacts with LXC