# No internet access in certain apps randomly

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, suspend

This mostly happens when the computer starts back up from sleep, but it's also happened randomly during use, though less frequently. About 1 in 5 times from sleep, during use I could count on my hand. It's been happening for a couple of months now on 16.10.

It seems to affect most apps, firefox, my-weather-indicator complains that it has no internet access, etc. Chrome on the otherhand still works fine and gets full internet access. Seems to be the only app that's not affected, though I haven't tested many.

I'll still connected to WiFI home network, just certain apps don't get internet. Restarting the apps proves futile. Changing from 5ghz to 2.4ghz wifi doesn't change anything. Neither does restarting networking with `systemctl restart networking` nor `ifdown -a` and `ifup -a` or using any of the GUI options in the networking applet. The only thing that has brought it back to normal has been rebooting my computer.

Edit:
rfkill list; lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net:

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [17aa:21f3]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1311]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: I assume you're running this on a laptop can you post a make and model?

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `rfkill list; lspci  -nnk | grep -iA3 net`  Thanks

Comment: @ThompsonDawes Lenovo Thinkpad X230

Comment: @Jeremy31 Question edited with requested result

Comment: Could you add the output of `grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf` to check if it share same cause as this post https://askubuntu.com/q/847882/26246

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some more testing when my connection dropped recently and no application had internet access other than chrome, and pinging google's DNS `ping 8.8.8.8`. Which lead me to seeing if changing the default DNS server to Google's might help. Bingo, internet connection restored after restarting wifi. Not sure why the issue happened, but I'm glad I have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you already came up with a solution (likely your ISPs DNS was having intermittent issues), but perhaps you should consider having Google's DNS server as your primary DNS (8.8.8.8) and Level 3's DNS server (4.2.2.3) as your secondary DNS server - that way if something cannot be resolved on the primary DNS or the primary DNS goes down, it will fall back to the other DNS server.